# Import single OSM feature XML into QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, xml

I am aware of the great QGIS plugin QuickOSM to download OSM features into QGIS, and I know that QGIS supports importing a `.osm` file that was downloaded from an exported view [like this one](https://www.openstreetmap.org/export#map=17/-27.45884/152.88001), however: how does one import a single OSM feature exported as XML?

1. Go to an OSM feature, e.g.: https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/23922428
2. Click on "Download XML", which is the same as using this link: https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/23922428
3. Try to import into QGIS

Using QGIS 3.16 on Ubuntu 18.04, the import dialogue asks me what kind of features I want to import, but they are all empty once in the project. I tried using the extensions `.xml` and `.osm` on the file, but it didn't help.

Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/23922428 only contains references to the nodes this way consists of, but it doesn't include these nodes directly. Try to add `/full` at the end of the URL, i.e. try importing https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/23922428/full instead.

Comment: Fabulous, thank you! I wondering why it isn't giving the `full` version of it. What would be the use of having the data with only the references? Wouldn't most data users want the full data?

Comment: Yes, most data users will need the full details. However, this [OSM API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) is not really meant for data users. It is mainly an editing API. On the other hand, the full version is also typically required for editing. So, not really sure why it isn't the default.